# Angular ng-options isn't set by the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an angular view where the user can pick an option in a select. (The data of the select comes from an API, so it's JSON object).

Here is one of my select (don't look at my object's structure) :

```
<select ng-options="team.logo as team.logo.title for team in teams"
        ng-model="live.metadata.teams.home.infos"
        class="form-control">
</select>
```

In my controller, I have an empty model which is set well when the client selects a new option.

The value stored in the model by the select is an JSON object with id, title, etc.

In this view, the client can create a team and all works fine. The problem appears when the client wants to edit one of its teams.

I have exactly the same select with ng-options (in another state, [brother of the previous view] "edit" for example), but this time the model isn't empty (it contains a JSON object of a recently created team with exactly the same structure). So I want the select takes the value of the model, to show the name in the select for example.

But nothing appears. The select seems to be disconnected from the model, but when you pick up another option in the select it changes the model well so the ng-options and the ng-model sync well.

I don't know where it can come from...

(I guess it's not a problem of child scopes, I tested it and nothing changed).

Here's an example of object given by the API :

```
{
    logo: {
        nid: "71",
        title: "Team Name 1",
        type: "team",
        logo: {
            src: "imageURL",
            alt: ""
        }
    }
},
{
    logo: {
        nid: "72",
        title: "Team Name 2",
        type: "team",
        logo: {
            src: "imageURL",
            alt: ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the `track by` option of `ng-options`.

Comment: Could you show us the problematic html and javascript in combination?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos : I already try to `track by team.logo.nid` or to `track by team.logo` but nothing change.

Comment: @BenjaminSchüller : I just add the object structure and the html is at the top of the post. The select normally show the `title` prop of the object.

Comment: @MaximeLafarie can you post repro in plnkr or something like that?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes i'll do this!

Comment: @AlekseyL. Here is **exactly** my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25884/ You can see the select isn't set, but when you select another option, it changes the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default angular watches the model by reference. To overcome this `track by` can be used. It didn't work for you because of nested objects (see [select as and track by documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)), to fix this I've selected "logos" into another array.

Here's working demo https://jsfiddle.net/1a7s9xqb/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my test

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('test', test);
  
test.$inject = ['$scope'];

function test($scope) {
  $scope.teams = [{
    logo: {
      nid: "71",
      title: "Team Name 1",
      type: "team",
      logo: {
        src: "imageURL",
        alt: ""
      }
    }
  },
                  {
                    logo: {
                      nid: "72",
                      title: "Team Name 2",
                      type: "team",
                      logo: {
                        src: "imageURL",
                        alt: ""
                      }
                    }
                  }];
  
  $scope.selectedTeam = $scope.teams[0].logo;
  $scope.selectedTeam2 = { //logo
      nid: "71",
      title: "Team Name 1",
      type: "team",
      logo: {
        src: "imageURL",
        alt: ""
      }
    };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test" >
  <select ng-options="team.logo as team.logo.title for team in teams"
          ng-model="selectedTeam"
          class="form-control">
  </select>
</div>
```

In your scenario you have to set the logo as the model.
And the logo has to be the same reference as in teams.

Comment: Yes thank you, this is the result I'm looking for, but it doesn't reproduce my problem, see here : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25884/

Comment: Ok, i see. The best solutiion in my opinion is to save the whole team in live-data. Then you can work with "track by". I have forked your fiddle to demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/jcdkL52e/